# Suspicious error ErrorException: file_get_contents()

Tags: php, laravel

I have a complete ecommerce solution made with Laravel. The system conveniently sends an email whenever an error happens, so I can address it quickly.

Today I received this error which I have not seen before. I understand it happens when the requested file does not exist, but what looks suspicious to me is that it is requesting some "testajabang" file which I don't really identify, I searched for it in the files and database and found nothing.

I'm a little bit paranoid about the system's security being breached. Besides that, the rest of the error log doesn't make that much sense to me, so I would really appreciate if you can help me identify what the rest of the stack trace really means, and if possible, I would like to have any suggestion to analyze the security of my system.

```
[2021-03-19 02:13:08] local.ERROR: file_get_contents(testajabang): failed to open stream: No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): file_get_contents(testajabang): failed to open stream: No such file or directory at /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/facade/ignition/src/Solutions/MakeViewVariableOptionalSolution.php:75)
[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'file_get_conten...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 75, Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/facade/ignition/src/Solutions/MakeViewVariableOptionalSolution.php(75): file_get_contents('testajabang')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/facade/ignition/src/Solutions/MakeViewVariableOptionalSolution.php(67): Facade\\Ignition\\Solutions\\MakeViewVariableOptionalSolution->makeOptional(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/facade/ignition/src/Http/Controllers/ExecuteSolutionController.php(19): Facade\\Ignition\\Solutions\\MakeViewVariableOptionalSolution->run(Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(48): Facade\\Ignition\\Http\\Controllers\\ExecuteSolutionController->__invoke(Object(Facade\\Ignition\\Http\\Requests\\ExecuteSolutionRequest), Object(Facade\\Ignition\\SolutionProviders\\SolutionProviderRepository))
#5 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(255): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Facade\\Ignition\\Http\\Controllers\\ExecuteSolutionController), '__invoke')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(197): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(691): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/facade/ignition/src/Http/Middleware/IgnitionConfigValueEnabled.php(25): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#10 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Facade\\Ignition\\Http\\Middleware\\IgnitionConfigValueEnabled->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure), 'enableRunnableS...')
#11 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/facade/ignition/src/Http/Middleware/IgnitionEnabled.php(23): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Facade\\Ignition\\Http\\Middleware\\IgnitionEnabled->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(693): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#15 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(668): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(634): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#17 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(623): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#22 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#24 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(87): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#30 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#34 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 /var/www/vhosts/thegardenshop.com.mx/httpdocs/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 {main}
```

Comment: This is far too broad a question, and not programming related. I will say though, that under ***no circumstances*** should you have `facade/ignition` even installed on a production server, let alone serving errors to the public. I would suggest getting someone in to review the work of your programmer if that's the kind of work they do.

Comment: I can also add that the user can use an error tracker like [Sentry](https://sentry.io) for a more easy tracking solution than sending raw email ! It is even free !